# Wrap text at 100 character mark

Tags: php

I have a program which divides the word separately. But I want it to divide the words which fit into 100 characters. This means I want to get the output of those first words that fit into 100 characters.

**Here is my PHP:**

```
<?php
function str_split_len($str, $len)
{
    if( $len > strlen($str) )
    {
        return false;
    }

    $strlen = strlen($str);
    $result = '';
    $words = ($strlen / $len);

    for( $x = 1; $x <= $len; $x++ )
    {
        $result .= '<div>'.substr($str, 0, $words).'</div>';
        $str = substr($str, $words, $strlen); 
    }

    return $result;
}

/* Example */
$res = str_split_len("Split me !haha!", 3);
echo $res;
?>
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are asking. If you have a sentence of more than 100 characters, you want to cut of the sub string that  comes after the 100 characters?

Answer (score -1):

if you want first 100 characters from your string you can use function substr

```
   $length_limit = 20; // you can set limit here what ever you want
   $str = "hello aaaaaaaaaaaaaa bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb"; // total 37
   echo substr($str, 0, $length_limit);
```

Output will be first 20 characters:

hello aaaaaaaaaaaaaa